# Integrate Handlebars into a Backbone Boilerplate app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

Is there a sample app or tutorial on how to integrate Handlebars into a Backbone Boilerplate app?

Answer (score 3):

It is worth mentioning here that Backbone Boilerplate's creator, Tim Branyen, just added support for Handlebars integration.

https://github.com/tbranyen/boilerplate-handlebars-layoutmanager/commit/1270608f4cb62bea6bd89a46e098210b9f075968

This is not a tutorial, but should point you in the right direction to integrate Handlebars with your app.